# Using nltk to find the correct definition of each word in a sentence

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I'm currently working on making a sentiment analyzer for book reviews. I'm using micro-WNOP instead of wordnet as it only contains synsets related to opinions.
Here's a sample of my code

```
while(z<len(lines)): #lines is an array where each element is a sentence
  word=lines[z]
  wor=nltk.word_tokenize(word)
  result=nltk.pos_tag(wor)
  while(x<len(result)):
      #token converts Penn Treebank POS tags to wordnet tags
      result[x]=result[x][0] + token(result[x][1])
      x+=1
  lines[z]=result
  z+=1
  x=0
```

My issue is that while I can tag a word as a noun, verb etc. I cannot get the correct definition for that word i.e real can mean true or tangible. This is a problem because micro-MNOP formats its words like this: 
real#a#2, where #a tells us it's an adjective and #2 means it's the second definition.

I'm even sure this is possible but if it is, I'd be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Where I found micro-MNOP: http://www-3.unipv.it/wnop/

Comment: Getting a computer to *understand words* is probably a little out-of-scope for a SO question.

Comment: Some simple approaches just calculate the average of all meanings of a word. I am not use if you can understand the exact meaning in a simple way, but you can try some statistical models, machine learning, etc.

Comment: I'm not looking for code, I'm just hoping someone might have an idea where to look to go about this sort of thing. I've been researching papers for days trying to find something suitable.

Comment: @YuriMalheiros that seems like a really good idea.

Comment: You could try using [this](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~ychoi/connotation/) instead.  It maps nouns and verbs to their likely positive/negative values.

Comment: What you are asking for is WSD and is an open problem in computational linguistics. There are many different approaches to this problem. However, micro-MNOP seems to be tagged with wordnet - synsets, which is quite fortunate, as WSD often relies on machine - learning and there are some large corpora like SemCor out there which can provide training data.
One common approach is the so called Most-Frequent-Sense baseline, which simply chooses the most common sense in all situation. It is actually a very good baseline, so depending on your needs this might be sufficient for you.